# Injecting Internal Classes into Azure WebJob Functions

Tags: c#, azure, unity-container, azure-webjobs

Is there any way for the default `Functions` class that comes in WebJob projects to be `internal`?  We are using a job activator to inject via Unity some dependencies that are `internal`, which requires that the `Functions` class also be `internal`.  When running the web job, we are seeing the following error:

`No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).`

When we make all the dependencies `public`, it works fine, so I know there's nothing wrong with my triggers or my job host config.

Here's my Program class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration
        {
            JobActivator = new Activator(new UnityContainer())
        };
        config.UseServiceBus();
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

Here's a simplified version of my Functions class:

```
internal class Functions
{
    private readonly IMyInternalDependency _dependency;

    public Functions(IMyInternalDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public function DoSomething([ServiceBusTrigger("my-queue")] BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        // Do something with the message
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about WebJobs, but you can have a private or internal class implement a public interface, and pass that object around as its interface.

Comment: Can you post some of the code, or an example of the code to get some context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make the `Functions` class public. That appears to be just how Azure WebJobs works. You don't need to expose your concrete internal classes publicly. Just the interfaces:

```
public interface IDoStuffPublically
{
    void DoSomething();
}

interface IDoStuffInternally
{
    void DoSomething();
    void DoSomethingInternally();
}

class DoStuff : IDoStuffPublically, IDoStuffInternally
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void DoSomethingInternally()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then your `Functions` class:

```
public class Functions
{
    public Functions(IDoStuffPublically stuff)
    {
        _stuff = stuff;
    }

    private IDoStuffPublically _stuff;

    // ...
}
```

And Unity will do something like this:

```
var job = new Functions(new DoStuff());
```

---

Dave commented:

> It's frustrating that I cannot simply set the internals visible to the WebJob SDK...

You *might* be able to accomplish this... *miiiiiiiiiight* be able to...

There is a way for an assembly or executable to grant another assembly the permission to access internal members. I've done this before on a class library to allow my unit tests to call internal methods on a class as part of setting up a unit test.

If you know which assembly in Azure WebJobs actually creates the instance of your Functions class, and the assembly that invokes the methods on that class, you could white list those assemblies.

Crack open **AssemblyInfo.cs** and add one or more lines:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.Azure.Something.Something")]
```

Reference: [InternalsVisibleToAttribute class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Related reading: [.Net Tips – using InternalsVisibleTo attribute to help testing non-public methods](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-using-internalsvisibleto-attribute-to-help-testing-non-public-methods/)

I'm not sure which assemblies you would need to add, though.

Comment: It's frustrating that I cannot simply set the internals visible to the WebJob SDK, but oh well.  This seems to be the best solution.  Thanks.

Comment: In the AssemblyInfo.cs file you can make the `internal`s visible to another Assembly. I wonder if that would work, as long as you know what Assembly the WebJob is run from...

Comment: @Dave: I've updated my question with directions for a possible solution.

Comment: I actually tried that before I posted, but to no avail.  It's certainly possible I didn't stumble across the correct assembly name, but I tried the following and they didn't work:  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors

Answer (score 1):

When using Triggers with the Webjob SDK, you never register the functions to be executed.

When the jobhost starts (`new JobHost(config).RunAndBlock()`), it discoverers the functions to be executed based on parameter attributes.

Let's have a look at your code:

```
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration
    {
        JobActivator = new Activator(new UnityContainer())
    };
    config.UseServiceBus();
```

Because you specify that you want to use servicebus, when the jobhost starts, it will discover and register (index) all the functions that have a parameter with the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute.

I assume that the SDK uses something like [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d(v=vs.110).aspx) to index the functions so don't know if it is (possible and) easy to get attributes from an internal class.